# Expression in pine script conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The goal is to have a safety in case of market goes south

How can I express in pine script:

```
If "LONG" position and signal == 0.0 are TRUE then

longSafety is true
```

I tried this code

```
longSafetyMem = false
longSafetyMem := long ? true : signal == 0.0 ? true : longSafetyMem[1]
longSafety = long and not(longSafetyMem[1])

plotshape(longSafety, title='lSafety', text='lSafety', location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(#fbb402, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

and it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
longSafety = long and signal == 0.0 ? true : false
```

Here I used a Ternary conditional operator to check the condition: If the condition is true, I assign a `true` value; if the condition is false, I assigned a `false` value. You may use any assigned value you need, but in this case it makes sense to use a bool.

More about Ternary conditional operator in the [reference documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_?:).

Comment: Good job. Thank you all. It is working. Can you help me with more advanced Ternary conditional https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77008703/expression-in-pine-script-when-meet-certain-conditions

Comment: edit that post in order I could make an answer, not comment
because in comment I can't write code correctly

Comment: Sorry I tried to edit, but this questions is still closed. I opened the new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77032358/expression-in-pine-script-when-met-certain-conditions